# Incompatibility between svjour3 and microtype

Tags: microtype, incompatibility, sv-classes

There seems to be an incompatibility between the `svjour3` document class for Springer journals and the `microtype` package. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This results in 90 lines of the form

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 63 was incomplete)
```

being written to standard out.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The size option file of the class (`svjour3.clo`) defines the font sizes `\normalsize`, `\small` and `\footnotesize` so that they contain two `\if`s. E.g. :

```
\renewcommand\normalsize{%
\if@twocolumn
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{12.5pt}%
\else
   \if@smallext
      \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \else
      \@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5pt}{11.5pt}%
   \fi
\fi
   \abovedisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \belowdisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \abovedisplayshortskip=0.0 mm plus6pt
   \belowdisplayshortskip=2 mm plus4pt minus 4pt
   \let\@listi\@listI}
```

That's rather unusual and it obviously confuse `microtype`. I don't understand why they put the if-switches in the font definitions - I doubt that they want to switch the sizes inside a document. Perhaps they only want to avoid to have to copy the `\abovedisplayskip` part around.

You will have to rearrange the definitions:

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\makeatletter
\if@twocolumn
  \renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{12.5pt}%
   \abovedisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \belowdisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \abovedisplayshortskip=0.0 mm plus6pt
   \belowdisplayshortskip=2 mm plus4pt minus 4pt
   \let\@listi\@listI}%

  \renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small{8.5pt}\@xpt
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \parsep 0\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus\p@
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
               \itemsep0\p@}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}

\else
  \if@smallext
   \renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt\@xiipt
   \abovedisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \belowdisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \abovedisplayshortskip=0.0 mm plus6pt
   \belowdisplayshortskip=2 mm plus4pt minus 4pt
   \let\@listi\@listI}%

  \renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@viiipt{9.5pt}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \parsep 0\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus\p@
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
               \itemsep0\p@}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
 \else
  \renewcommand\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize{9.5pt}{11.5pt}%
   \abovedisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \belowdisplayskip=3 mm plus6pt minus 4pt
   \abovedisplayshortskip=0.0 mm plus6pt
   \belowdisplayshortskip=2 mm plus4pt minus 4pt
   \let\@listi\@listI}%  

  \renewcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@viiipt{9.25pt}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \parsep 0\p@ \@plus1\p@ \@minus\p@
               \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
               \itemsep0\p@}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
  \fi
\fi
\let\footnotesize\small
\makeatother

\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: “I don't understand why they put the if-switches in the font definitions” ... looking at the *before* and *after* code, it seems that they were trying to factor our common parts of the code. (?)

Comment: Thanks Ulrike! I copied the svglov3.clo file to svglov3-fix.clo, made the relevant changes, and then passed the `glov3-fix` option to the document class which loads mine instead.

Comment: "I doubt that they want to switch the sizes inside a document" - maybe they wanted to do just that, e.g., whenever one switches between single and two columns?