# \begingroup\def trick vs. macro delimiters vs. conditionals

Tags: compiling, microtype, key-value, sv-classes, newtx

In this MWE, combining `newtxtext` and `microtype` leads to a compilation error (Extra `\else`). This particular example is inspired by the `svjour3` document class, but I reduced it to the `article` class and a simple redefinition of `\normalsize`. You would think that an `\iftrue ... \else\fi` construction should not change much compared to just `...`, yet it does:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldnormalsize\normalsize

% this works!
%\let\normalsize\oldnormalsize

% this works!
%\renewcommand\normalsize{\oldnormalsize}

% this works!
%\renewcommand\normalsize{\iffalse\else\fi\oldnormalsize}

% inspired by svglov3.clo. Does not work!
%\renewcommand\normalsize{\iffalse\else\oldnormalsize\fi}

% Does not work, either!
\renewcommand\normalsize{\iftrue\oldnormalsize\else\fi}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
    Anything
\end{document}
```

Is that a bug in `newtxtext` or `microtype`, or are the `svjour3` developers doing something that should be avoided? I cannot really see what that might be.

Inverting the order of `microtype` and `newtxtext` gets rid of that error, by the way. I have not found anything helpful on that topic, but I wonder whether `microtype` should be loaded only after all font packages have been loaded. A quick test suggests that in my longer document, the order of the two packages does not matter.

The problem can be isolated to this MWE (see my answer for details, I did not want to flood this question). Removing any of the three unneeded `iftrue`, `\iffalse` constructions fixes the problem, too, as does reordering the `\ifs` in `\ShowError`. (I can only reproduce this with `\iffalse` surrounded by an `\iftrue`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\CommandOne}[3]{#1,#2,#3}
\newcommand{\CommandTwo}{\iftrue\CommandOne{1}{2}{3}\else\fi}
% this works:
% \renewcommand{\CommandTwo}{\CommandOne{1}{2}{3}}

\def\ShowError{
    \iftrue
        \iffalse
        \else
            \begingroup
                \def\CommandOne##1##2##3\@nil{\endgroup}
                \CommandTwo\@nil
        \fi
    \else
    \fi
}
\ShowError

\begin{document}
    X
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error happens when `microtype.cfg` is doing `\DeclareMicrotypeSet{basicmath}{...}` and is probably a by-product of how `xkeyval` manages keys and values. On the other hand, a redefinition of `\normalsize` (if it's the right thing to do in the first place), should go *after* packages have been loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24853/incompatibility-between-svjour3-and-microtype

Comment: I feel this question (especially the answer) has become much more general than that other question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: `\renewcommand\normalsize{\iftrue\expandafter\oldnormalsize\else\fi}` fixes your first MWE.  Likewise, `\renewcommand\normalsize{\iffalse\else\expandafter\oldnormalsize\fi}`

Comment: In your 2nd MWE, this works: `\newcommand{\CommandTwo}{\iftrue\def\next{\CommandOne{1}{2}{3}}\else\def\next{}\fi\next}`

Comment: @StevenBSegletes thanks, this might be the answer indeed. It seems this could/should be taken to the `svjour3` maintainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only the small MWE you already produced this becomes quite explainable:

First lets take a look at the context this results in. The following is just the stuff this results in which I've replaced each macro with its replacement text indented by 6 additional spaces (in case of a macro inside of an `\if`-block this results in 8, as I indent those by 2 spaces):

```
\iftrue
        \iffalse
        \else
                \iffalse
                \else
                        \begingroup
                        \def\set@fontsize#1\@nil{\endgroup}%
                              \iftrue
                                \normalsize
                              \else
                              \fi
                        \@nil
                \fi
        \fi
\else
\fi
```

Now `\normalsize` expands to some checks and then `\set@fontsize`, so if we ignore the checks (and the usual arguments to `\set@fontsize` as they don't matter here) this becomes:

```
\iftrue
        \iffalse
        \else
                \iffalse
                \else
                        \begingroup
                        \def\set@fontsize#1\@nil{\endgroup}%
                              \iftrue
                                      \set@fontsize
                              \else
                              \fi
                        \@nil
                \fi
        \fi
\else
\fi
```

If we now just expand our temporary definition of `\set@fontsize` without evaluating all the `\if`s and `\else`s before, it'll remove everything up to and including `\@nil` and instead leaves an `\endgroup`, so we get:

```
\iftrue
        \iffalse
        \else
                \iffalse
                \else
                        \begingroup
                        \def\set@fontsize#1\@nil{\endgroup}%
                              \iftrue
                                      \endgroup
                \fi
        \fi
\else
\fi
```

Now lets remove the contents of `\begingroup...\endgroup` as they aren't interesting anymore except for the contained `\iftrue`:

```
\iftrue
        \iffalse
        \else
                \iffalse
                \else
                              \iftrue
                \fi
        \fi
\else
\fi
```

And now the issue becomes apparent. Let's just re-indent this to be more readable:

```
\iftrue
  \iffalse
  \else
    \iffalse
    \else
      \iftrue
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
  \fi
```

Next, we'll remove matching pairs of `\if...\else...\fi` blocks, first the inner-most `\iftrue`:

```
\iftrue
  \iffalse
  \else
    \iffalse
    \else
    \fi
  \else
  \fi
```

Now the inner-most `\iffalse`:

```
\iftrue
  \iffalse
  \else
  \else
  \fi
```

and we arrive at the `Extra \else`.

The issue is that your temporary `\set@fontsize`-definition will have removed important bits of an `\if`-construct and the result you get after this will be unbalanced `\if`-`\else`-`\fi` instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I'll summarize here what I found starting with @egreg's answer. The MWE below is what I could reduce it to, independent of `svjour3`, `newtxtext` and `microtype`, by tediously following the sequence of executed functions. What I end up not understanding is this `\MT@get@size` from `microtype`, which looks like this:

```
\def\MT@get@size{%
  ...
  \ifx\@tempa\relax \else
    \begingroup
      \def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4\@nil{\endgroup\def\MT@val{##2}}%
      \@tempa\@nil
  \fi
  ...
}
```

This looks nasty to me: I have no clue why `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` and `{`,`}` appear interleaved there. (Turns out it is this: [Explanations about \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61223/explanations-about-begingroup-edef-x-endgroup))

So in some sense, `keyval` does not like the `\begingroup` trick in combination with the `\iftrue ... \else\fi`, but I have not been able to isolate this any further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\newcommand{\fancysize}{\iftrue\normalsize\else\fi}

\makeatletter
\define@key{foo}{bar}[]{
    \begingroup
        \def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4\@nil{\endgroup}
        \fancysize
        \@nil
    }
\setkeys{foo}{bar}

\begin{document}
    X
\end{document}
```

Interestingly, removing `\@nil` works:

```
\define@key{foo}{bar}[]{
    \begingroup
    \def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4{\endgroup}
    \fancysize
}
```

What are those `\@nil` for? (Answer: [Macro delimiter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36325/macro-delimiter))

Also, moving `\@nil` inside the `\iftrue...\else\fi` works:

```
\define@key{foo}{bar}[]{
    \begingroup
    \def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4\@nil{\endgroup}
    \iftrue\normalsize\@nil\else\fi
}
```

This suggests that in the non-working case, `\normalsize\else\fi\@nil` becomes `...\set@fontsize...\else\fi\@nil`, so `\else\fi` become parameters to `\set@fontsize`, where they don't match anything. It is really the combination of the `\begingroup\def` trick, macro delimiters, and a conditional expression. And all this is independent of much of `keyval`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

% similar to svjour3:
\newcommand{\fancysize}{\iftrue\normalsize\else\fi}

% isolated from microtype and keyval
\def\KV@foo@bar@default{
    \begingroup
        \def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4\@nil{\endgroup}
        \fancysize
        \@nil
    }

% isolated from keyval
\def\KV@default{
    \iffalse\else
        \KV@foo@bar@default
    \fi
}

\def\KV@split{
    \iftrue
        \KV@default
    \else\fi
}

\KV@foo@bar@default % works!
\KV@default % works!
\KV@split % fails!

\begin{document}
    X
\end{document}
```

I wonder if that gives anyone a clue how to solve this in the general case...

```
% \documentclass{svjour3}

% \usepackage{newtxtext}
% \usepackage[config=foo]{microtype}

% \DeclareMicrotypeSet{}{size={normalsize}}

% \MT@DeclareSet{}{size={normalsize}}

% \renewcommand\MT@DeclareSet[3][]{\MT@map@clist@c\MT@features{{\MT@declare@sets{##1}{#2}{#3}}}}
% \MT@DeclareSet{}{size={normalsize}}

% \MT@map@clist@c\MT@features{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \MT@map@clist@c\MT@features{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \MT@exp@one@n\MT@map@clist@n\MT@features{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \MT@exp@one@n\MT@map@clist@n\MT@features{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \expandafter\MT@map@clist@n\expandafter{pr,ex,sp,kn,tr}{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \def\MT@map@clist@n#1#2{\def\MT@clist@function##1{#2}\MT@map@clist@#1,\@nil,\@nnil}
% \expandafter\MT@map@clist@n\expandafter{pr,ex,sp,kn,tr}{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}

% \def\MT@clist@function#1{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}
% \MT@map@clist@ pr,ex,sp,kn,tr,\@nil,\@nnil

% \def\MT@clist@function#1{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}
% \MT@map@clist@ pr,\@nil,\@nnil

% \def\MT@clist@function#1{{\MT@declare@sets{#1}{}{size={normalsize}}}}
% \MT@clist@function{pr}

% \MT@declare@sets{pr}{}{size={normalsize}}

% \def\MT@declare@sets#1#2#3{\setkeys{MT@#1@set}{#3}}
% \MT@declare@sets{pr}{}{size={normalsize}}

% \setkeys{MT@pr@set}{size={normalsize}}

% \define@key{foo}{size}[]{\MT@map@clist@n{#1}{\def\MT@val{##1}\expandafter\MT@get@range\MT@val--\@nil}}
% \setkeys{foo}{size={normalsize}}

% \define@key{foo}{size}{\MT@map@clist@n{#1}{\def\MT@val{##1}\expandafter\MT@get@range\MT@val--\@nil}}
% \setkeys{foo}{size={normalsize}}

% \define@key{foo}{size}{\def\MT@val{normalsize}\expandafter\MT@get@range\MT@val--\@nil}
% \setkeys{foo}{size={normalsize}}

% \define@key{foo}{bar}{\def\MT@val{normalsize}\expandafter\MT@get@range\MT@val--\@nil}
% \setkeys{foo}{bar=foobar}

% \define@key{foo}{bar}[]{\MT@get@range normalsize--\@nil}
% \setkeys{foo}{bar}

% \def\MT@get@range#1{\def\MT@val{#1}\MT@get@size}
% \define@key{foo}{bar}[]{\MT@get@range{normalsize}}
% \setkeys{foo}{bar}

% \define@key{foo}{bar}[]{\def\MT@val{normalsize}\MT@get@size}
% \setkeys{foo}{bar}

% \define@key{foo}{bar}[]{\MT@let@cn\@tempa{normalsize}\iffalse\else\begingroup\def\set@fontsize##1##2##3##4\@nil{\endgroup\def\MT@val{##2}}\@tempa\@nil\fi}
% \setkeys{foo}{bar}
```

Comment: Can you edit this so it is clearly answer? The ending sounds as if it is still part of the question, which is really confusing. (If it is part of the question, it should be part of the question. Or another question. Or some question-thing somewhere ....)